# First time Domain Hosting in the AWS directly

Tags: javascript, sys

I have Domain which i purchased from the Domain.google Zeta and now i am trying to make it as live Domain by using the AWS instance and i have EC2 instance can you help me out with the procedure to some sample .

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to host your website using AWS, and then point your Domain to that aws hosted instance IP.

That would make it live i believe.

Hosting website on Aws
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Comment: i have did the same procedure for hosting the domain but still my domain is getting connection error in the url

Comment: Thnaks for the response can you help on this how can we do this .

Comment: My contact : +91 9591983578

Comment: This site can’t be reached
www.example.com took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT